# What is the type of this light bulb?

Tags: lighting

I need to replace this light-bulb. It is very slim and I have never seen it anywhere else. What is the light bulb's type?

[image: photo]

Comment: Note the "CE" marking on this fixture is not the official "CE" logo and does not indicate conformance to EU standards. See https://www.chinaimportal.com/blog/ce-marking-importing-china-complete-guide/ and scroll past the pictures of equipment bursting into flames and down to "Labeling Requirements".

Comment: Or https://support.ce-check.eu/hc/en-us/articles/360008642600

Comment: @BrianDrummond The wrong styling of the CE symbol does not prove the device is non-conforming. [Quoth Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking#China_Export): _... China Export ... **However, the European Commission says that this is a misconception.** ... The Commission responded that it was unaware of the existence of any "Chinese Export" mark and that, in its view, the incorrect application of the CE marking on products was unrelated to incorrect depictions of the symbol, although both practices took place._

Comment: @marcelm of course it doesn't *prove* non conformance. But it's a big Caveat Emptor.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Note that `ce-check.eu` has no affiliation with the EU, but is the website of a consultancy company. The whole "China export" thing makes zero sense: there is no motivation whatsoever for a Chinese company to put a marking on a product that says "This is a safe, CE-marked product" to the general public but "This is a fake CE mark" to people in the know. Why would they do that, instead of putting the correct CE logo on the product? It makes much more sense to assume that some companies know exactly what the symbol is supposed to look like and some don't.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I can only guess that marking your product with the authentic design (without the paper trail to support claims of compliance) is an invitation to a hefty lawsuit. But your guess is as good as mine. (I first saw this fake mark on a chandelier bought from a major British retail chain ... when it failed the day after I installed it in our living room. One anecdote proves nothing, of course, except their buyers didn't know what it looked like either.)

Comment: @BrianDrummond Using a mark so similar would make no difference to any lawsuit. In fact, it might make it worse, as it adds another level of deliberate deception. In any case, in reality, such a lawsuit would never get off the ground, because the Chinese authorities wouldn’t cooperate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like a Linear Halogen R7s but you need to measure it to get the right length eg 78mm/118mm.

Comment: Wipe off the glass part after installing the new one. Your body oils will cause premature failure because of the extreme heat generated by these bulbs.

Comment: If you accidentally touch the bulb while handling it, don't just wipe it off with a rag or something. Use a clean rag/towel/etc. and some anhydrous (99%) rubbing alcohol, to make 100% sure there's no trace of oil left. But really, just make sure you only handle the bulb with a clean cloth and don't actually touch it in the first place.

Comment: It's actually salt (sodium chloride) not oils that gets into the quartz (silica) envelope and causes it to weaken and fail, so wear clean gloves, and wash it if you accidentally touch it.

Answer (score 10):

There  is no doubt that is a halogen tube style bulb. These types of bulbs have a risk to them; they get extremely hot, and can start fires.

Unless the socket can be changed to another bulb type, I advise discarding this entire fixture and replacing with LED. Aside from the higher fire risk, they also are quite inefficient.  This 100W lamp replaces about 140W of incandescent, but a 20W CFL will replace it, as will a 15W LED.  Your local power company may well have incentives/rebates/bounties for the elimination of such lights, because paying you to get rid of such fixtures is *actually cheaper for them* than building out the power plant capacity to power it.

My rule of thumb on energy use is $1/watt/year for a load on 24x7 (like that cable box), assuming 12 cents a KWH.  A load on a fraction of the time is that fraction of $1.  I.E. A bathroom light that might be on 10% of the time, saving 85 watts means saving $85 x 10% = $8.50/year.

Comment: Incandescent light bulbs are no longer sold in the EU because of their inefficiency, with some exceptions.  Pressurized halogen bulbs are one of the exceptions - they aren't as efficient as LED, but they are not *that* bad.

Comment: @MartinBonner Generally all the exceptions are because there is no alternative, e.g. Oven lights or the difficulty of putting any alternative technology in the very small space of a halogen tube bulb.  That is why I say junk the fixture.  ...yes, we have "60 watt" equivalent halogens that are 45 watts. The "60 watt" CFLs were 11 watts  The "60 watt" LEDs are 7.

Comment: It's not terribly hard to convert many halogen lamps to standard screw in type bulb sockets. I've done it with several of my old Torchiere lamps. You'll have to buy the new socket. Changes to switching is usually not necessary. Once done, you can put an LED in there.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Good point!

Comment: You're being overly alarmist about Halogen bulbs. People have been using them for... what, 40 or 50 years now, all over the world. Yes, they can theoretically shatter. That's why you don't just put them at arm's reach. Yes, they're not efficient like CFLs or LEDs, but - OP shouldn't replace a series of light fixtures because of this consideration.

Comment: @einpoklum The problem is **not** just shattering. They run **very hot** and are therefore a huge fire hazard *even when functioning as designed*. There was a big thing I remember many years back to provide free metal grids to put on top - to me that was a signal of just how dangerous these things are. I had a couple and got rid of them. Here is a link https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11020053 to a published medical journal article - that's how bad these things got!

Comment: As someone who switched mostly to CFL/LED 15 years ago... I have to note that you failed to put scare quotes around "equivalent". It's only in the last 3 or so that LEDs have acquired a CRE to be a competent replacement.

Comment: @manassehkatz: They run hot, true. That doesn't make them a "huge fire hazard"; that depends on where and how they're installed - and usually they're installed in such a way that effectively, they aren't a significant hazard.

Comment: @einpoklum Installed in an oven or other fixed appliance - great. Installed in an undercabinet fixture - OK. Installed in a portable torchiere, *easily knocked down by kids or pets*, *easily placed next to draperies*, etc. **not so good**.

Comment: @manassehkatz : Fair enough about torchiere. OP's photo seems to be a wall-mounted fixture though.

Comment: In the house, lighting is not usually responsible for a very big chunck of electricity use, so, making "your meter spin like a top" is hyperbolic nonsense, even with halogens.

Comment: @fredsbend Alright, you sold me. I backed way off.  I'm leaving the part about power plants in, though; that part is undisputable.

Comment: @einpoklum alright, I've toned it back significantly.

Comment: You can get LED bulbs that will slot into a fixture like this (e.g. this [one from Philips](https://www.lighting.philips.co.uk/consumer/p/led-linear-tube-(dimmable)/8718696578735)). They work but may be more expensive and less bright than a new LED fixture.